# AWS : how to deploy app Nuxt.js with integreted REST API backend to AWS cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, nuxt.js, cloud

I want to deploy my full-stack application **Nuxt.js** with **api endpoint** integred (with **express.js**).
I can't separate my project which is a very big app...
I have trouble on how to deploy my app to **AWS cloud**, and I don't know how to choose between amplify or lambda while keeping the **lowest price** possible...

Comment: maybe this article could help: https://medium.com/@fernyettheplant/serverless-side-rendering-with-aws-lambda-nuxtjs-b94d15782af5

Comment: Hi Aziza - this is an opinionated question without more information so people (including myself) will vote for it to close as it isn't likely that we can get to a factual answer; please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic & then try focusing your question more